# PHP code in string

Tags: php

I was amazed I didn't found answer on Google for this answer.
So basically I have a PHP code which have to be stored in a variable as a string. Unfortunately PHP recognize the opening and ending tag not as a string but a PHP code... I want it as a string :)

```
        $settings_string =
                    '
                    <?php
                        //Locker ID
                        $userToSearch = '.$_POST["usertosearch"].';

                        //User Folder
                        $userFolder = '.$folder.';

                        //User Link
                        $userLink = '.$_POST["userlink"].';

                        // Username and pass
                        $affiliateuser = '.$_POST["affiliateuser"].';
                        $affiliatepassword = '.$_POST["affiliatepassword"].';
                    ?>
                    ';
```

Comment: Why you wanna do this? Please share your purpose, may be you will get better than this option.

Comment: I want to 'fwrite' it on a text document.

Comment: `Unfortunately PHP recognize the opening and ending tag`, No, it isn't. You are using the same quote type for encapsulation in your string, so that ends the encapsulation.

Comment: PHP should treat `'<?php'` as a string.

Comment: you cannot use < you have to use &lt

Comment: ..or if you want `$userToSearch` set to the value of `$_POST["usertosearch"]` then quote that. But this is dangerous. You are allowing users to write PHP.

Comment: @L.feir Why can't he/she?

Comment: You'll want to make sure your output is valid syntax, I think you are missing some quotes around the `$_POST`.....

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.
if u tell your purpose. so i can give you better than this.

```php
$settings_string ='
  <?php
    //Locker ID
    $userToSearch = \'.$_POST["usertosearch"].\';

    //User Folder
    $userFolder = \'.$folder.\';

    //User Link
    $userLink = \'.$_POST["userlink"].\';

    // Username and pass
    $affiliateuser = \'.$_POST["affiliateuser"].\';
    $affiliatepassword = \'.$_POST["affiliatepassword"].\';
  ?>
';
```

Now you have to use like this

```
$file = fopen('file_name.php', 'w');

fwrite($file, $settings_string);
```

Comment: i think this is perfect for you to fwrite use this

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the `$_POST` injected in there you still need to quote it properly in the output.

```
   $settings_string =
                '
                <?php
                    //Locker ID
                    $userToSearch = "'.$_POST["usertosearch"].'";  //add them quotes!!!!

                    //User Folder
                    $userFolder = "'.$folder.'";

                    //User Link
                    $userLink = "'.$_POST["userlink"].'";

                    // Username and pass
                    $affiliateuser = "'.$_POST["affiliateuser"].'";
                    $affiliatepassword = "'.$_POST["affiliatepassword"].'";
                ?>
                ';
```

I'll assume `$_POST["usertosearch"] = 'user'` currently in your output would be this.

```
       $userToSearch = user;
```

When instead you want

```
        $userToSearch = "user";
```

Above you will see the added double quote, to properly quote the strings in the output file.  That file still has to have valid syntax.

As a note, if any of the post values contain `"` your gonna have issues, unless you do `addslashes()` for them.

For example

```
 $userLink = "'.$_POST["userlink"].'";
```

Assume this is `$_POST["userlink"] = '<a href="#">link</a>'` OR

```
  $userLink = "<a href="#">link</a>";
```

See the issue with that.  When you'll want this

```
    $userLink = "<a href=\"#\">link</a>";
```

Answer (score -2):

Your looking for [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
<?php
    $settings_string ='
                    //Locker ID
                    $userToSearch = '.$_POST["usertosearch"].';

                    //User Folder
                    $userFolder = '.$folder.';

                    //User Link
                    $userLink = '.$_POST["userlink"].';

                    // Username and pass
                    $affiliateuser = '.$_POST["affiliateuser"].';
                    $affiliatepassword = '.$_POST["affiliatepassword"].';
                ';
eval($settings_string);
```

Comment: Never use `eval` on user provided data. `The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.`